# How to express PostgreSQL variable as a string

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

Is there any way how to express a variable in PostgreSQL as a string?

Example:

```
\set table_name countries
SELECT 'SELECT * FROM ' || CAST( :table_name, 'text' ) AS specificQuery;
```

leads to this error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ","
LINE 1: SELECT 'SELECT * FROM ' || CAST( countries, 'text' ) AS specificQuery;
```

From the line sample above is obvious, that it doesn't convert "countries" to a string, but it is expressed as name of column/table.

How do I convert it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?:

```
SELECT * FROM :"table_name";
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-VARIABLES

Comment: Using single quotes also works when you need a string: `SELECT 1 WHERE column = :'table_name';`. Also for concatenation: `SELECT 'abc_' || :'table_name' || '_xyz';`.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this :

```
SELECT 'SELECT * FROM ' || countries::text AS specificQuery;
```

Comment: I'm not sure you've got the original idea... I have countries as a content of a variable. Anyway, I guess you mean table_name::text or :table_name::text, but none of that works.